# command: cabal build all, falling back to older state

Tags: haskell, blockchain, cabal, cardano, cabal-dev

i am trying to install cardano-wallet by following this doc https://developers.cardano.org/docs/get-started/installing-cardano-wallet/

and getting this error while performing `cabal build all`

here is error that I am getting,

```
HEAD is now at 00ebe72 Added support for aeson-2.0, text-2.0, and GHC 9.2
Warning: The package list for 'hackage.haskell.org' is 146 days old.
Run 'cabal update' to get the latest list of available packages.
Warning: Requested index-state 2022-05-18T00:00:00Z is newer than
'hackage.haskell.org'! Falling back to older state (2022-03-02T05:17:47Z).
Resolving dependencies...
cabal: Could not resolve dependencies:
[__0] trying: cardano-wallet-2022.7.1 (user goal)
[__1] next goal: blockfrost-client-core (dependency of cardano-wallet)
[__1] rejecting: blockfrost-client-core-0.2.0.0 (conflict: cardano-wallet =>
blockfrost-client-core>=0.4 && <0.5)
[__1] skipping: blockfrost-client-core-0.1.0.0 (has the same characteristics
that caused the previous version to fail: excluded by constraint '>=0.4 &&
<0.5' from 'cardano-wallet')
[__1] fail (backjumping, conflict set: blockfrost-client-core, cardano-wallet)
After searching the rest of the dependency tree exhaustively, these were the
goals I've had most trouble fulfilling: cardano-wallet, blockfrost-client-core
```

Using cardano-node version 1.35.0 and and trying to install cardano-wallet v2022-7-1

Comment: Could you try `cabal update` before  `cabal build all`?

Comment: yeah I tried it but got error in ```cabal update```, anyways now its done.

thanks

Answer (score 1):

This is almost certainly due to an out-of-date cache of the list of packages (and their versions) available from Hackage. You can use

```
cabal update
```

to fetch the latest list; then try again.

Comment: I did cabal update but it is resulting with 416 status response

```$ cabal update

Downloading the latest package list from hackage.haskell.org
Unexpected response 416 for http://objects-us-east-1.dream.io/hackage-mirror/01-index.tar.gz```

Comment: ```cabal update``` worked.

Answer (score 0):

error solved by performing `cabal update` command